# How can I define a string that will ignore escape sequences?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Is there a way to write text in "quotes" that will ignore escape sequences? e.g. instead of:

```
"C:\\Folder\\Subfolder";
```

write:

```
{some character?}"C:\Folder\Subfolder";
```

Comment: Are you looking for [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)?

Comment: Instead of `"C:\\Folder\\Subfolder";` you could use `"C:/Folder/Subfolder";` and it would work as a path in most windows api functions.

Comment: @drescherjm ye, but in this case I have to replace all \ with /, and it's pretty the same as to add second \ to the path. I want to just copy the path and that's all, without editing it.

Comment: I guess it comes from habit. I use / all the time for the path separator when it type it. Even for #include statements in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want "raw" strings - the format is like `R"(string)"`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

To clarify, the parentheses *are* part of the format - the reference page explains it in more detail. So, to use your example, here's how you'd write it:

```
string path = R"(C:\Folder\Subfolder)";
```

Also, you were using the term "literal" wrong. Things like `'\n'` and `'\\'` are called [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). I edited your post with the correct terminology.

Comment: Note that the parentheses *are* significant. The (minimal) delimiters for a raw string literal are `R"(` and `)"`.